# Update SQL from Excel sheet using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am trying to update some records in SQL from excel sheet using VBA. I have a lot of records in the excel sheet so this is why I want to automate this. Below is a sample of the field I want to update "rmn_dr". "t_id" is unique in both tables. I want to update "rmn_dr" in the SQL "Job" table with values from "Excel Sheet"

```
Excel Sheet
t_id          rmn_dr
310449           16
310450           120
310451           256
310452           165.2


JOB (SQL Table)
t_id          rmn_dr
310449           2
310450           5
310451           7
310452          0
```

Can someone help me with the VBA code please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each field is text, try the following.

The assumption is that the data on the Excel sheet is listed from a1 Cell, including fields.

```
Sub setDAtaToServer()
    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" _
             & "Server=(local);" _
             & "Database=JOB;" _
             & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
             & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

    con.Open


    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE JOB SET rmn_dr='" & vDB(i, 2) & "' WHERE t_id='" & vDB(i, 1) & "' "
        cmd.Execute
    Next i

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```