# Looped SQL query with excel column values

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I need to run an update query on a table with about 500 entries in it. I need to update the column called pointvalue with different values based on the column agentname. So if I just needed to do it with one single value it would look like this.

```
UPDATE attendance SET PointValue = '5' WHERE AgentName = 'Example Value'
```

The kicker is that I need to do this with 500 different values for 500 different people. Currently I have each person's name and point value in an excel spreadsheet. Column A contains names, columb B contains values. Is there a way to write a VBA script that can run through the spreadsheet and run an update query for each row? Something like

```
UPDATE attendance SET PointValue = 'A2' WHERE AgentName = 'A1'

UPDATE attendance SET PointValue = 'B2' WHERE AgentName = 'B1'
```

and then on and on until it reaches the bottom?

Comment: Do you only need to do this once? if so use excel formula to build the query

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565661/update-sql-from-excel-sheet-using-vba/52569661?noredirect=1#comment92088685_52569661)

Comment: @MikeMiller I do only need to do this once. We're just moving from our old way of tracking these values to a SQL based solution so once they are in they are in for good.

Comment: You  can do it with vba.

Comment: @Dy.Lee I checked out the link you referred to earlier. That looks like it's exactly what I was looking for. Glad to know someone had the same issue before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a formula in the 3rd column which effectively builds the queries and then cut and paste to run them.

```
="UPDATE attendance SET PointValue = '" & A2 & "' WHERE AgentName = '" & A1 & "'"
```

You might get some SQL escaping issues but won't take long to fix.

Comment: So essentially I could just copy and paste all 500 individual queries into SSMS and it wold run them sequentially? This may be the simplest solution.