# SQL table update works, but only took value from one row

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am creating an automate file to update the currency rates in the CurrencyTable (dB) on a button click. I have refer to the example as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565661/update-sql-from-excel-sheet-using-vba).
My **Excel data** is as below:

```
CsName    Rate
AUD       1.23
BHD       2.23
BND       3.23
EUR       4.23
IDR       5.23
INR       6.23
MYR       7.23
OMR       8.23
SGD       9.23
THB       10.23
USD       11.23
```

The code seems to work fine, however it does not updating as per the Excel data, instead, it only took the 4th row value for everything.
[Here are the updated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUkqs.png).

Below are my codes:

```
Sub UpdateCR()

Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim i As Long
Dim vDB As Variant
Dim Ws As Worksheet

con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=1234;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Guest;Initial Catalog=ABC;Data Source=XYZ"
con.Open

Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
Set Ws = ActiveSheet

vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion

For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE CurrencyTable SET Rate='" & vDB(i, 2) & "' WHERE CsName ='" & vDB(i, 1) & "' "
    cmd.Execute
Next i

con.Close


MsgBox "Exchange rates successfully updated"

Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? Is it related to the UBound function?

Any helps on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the results as you did the source, i can't access the images at work.

Comment: hi , first vDB is a range there for vDB(i, 2) >> vDB(i, 2).value . and rate normally is number (doable, single ) and you update string ?  so   ( ...SET Rate=" & vDB(i, 2) & " WHERE......)

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, all the value in the Rate column were updated to 4.23 as the value in the 4th row.

Comment: Hi @xshen, I try to check using the F8 and the value looks okay for each line until the end of the rows. But once executed, the updated value turned out wrong.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code can you add one more line after cmd.Execute Cells(i,3) = "your update string", see what it prints

Comment: Have you stepped through the code, see when this happens, are all the executes creating the same issue, or is it just the 4 etc.  Put a breakpoint on the sql line and see what the command is

Comment: Hi @Bharat, I tried your suggestion and the results are same, all rows updated as the value in the 4th row, with additional column and all the data were printed as "your update string" in each rows (Column C).

Comment: Yes @Nathan_Sav, I used the F8 and the value looks okay for each line until the end of the rows. The command is "UPDATE CurrencyTable SET Rate='1.23' WHERE CsName ='AUD' " and loop until the last row. But the results are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all the CSNames correct in the table you're updating? Are they all set to EUR from something else, maybe coding this. May sound obvs, but just in case :)

Comment: 1) The top 4 row in the main table of the Currency (Currency, Country, Rates); from AUD-EUR have been deleted from the applications - hence causing only the top 4 is being updated. 2) Manual correction of the CsName field for the top 4 row from the main page resolve the issue, and the macros is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> *First of all this is not the answer, I am posting here to explain the
> troubleshooting as comments won't help.*

What I am saying is print the string of what is being executed in another column.
**For example:**
Once you try this, can you please show the image from the 3rd column?

```
    Sub UpdateCR()

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=1234;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Guest;Initial Catalog=ABC;Data Source=XYZ"
    con.Open
    
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE CurrencyTable SET Rate='" & vDB(i, 2) & "' WHERE CsName ='" & vDB(i, 1) & "' "
        cmd.Execute
        Cells(i, 3) = "UPDATE CurrencyTable SET Rate='" & vDB(i, 2) & "' WHERE CsName ='" & vDB(i, 1) & "' "
    Next i
    
    con.Close
    
    
    MsgBox "Exchange rates successfully updated"
    
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

For me the result looks like below, is it same for you?
[image]

Comment: Ops, apologize, I got you suggestion wrong! Haha. =D However, yes, my results are same as in your table above. But when I checked the updated table, it still takes after the 4th row.

Comment: Ok now, after each execution in loop check the values from the table are they changing. e.g until you reach EUR line, are the values for first 3 same as 4.23?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to test it. I tried changing the value of the 4th row to other number, but still same. Btw, I tried to copy the print string as in the Column C and run in the SQL, this is what I got. I looks kinda weird, but it somehow related to the issue that I am facing.

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

(11 rows affected) **at the 4th row it is showing all the 11 rows affected**

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

(0 rows affected)

Comment: wow that's interesting, can you please post the 4th statement as it is as i am suspecting something in query

Comment: That's what I thought too! UPDATE CurrencyTable SET Rate='4.23' WHERE CsName='EUR'

Comment: Are all the CSNames correct in the table you're updating?  Are they all set to EUR from something else, maybe coding this.   May sound obvs, but just in case :)

Comment: Great @Nathan! I checked the same as you said, and somehow, somewhere in other form (in the application) I found that all the CSName are EUR! It is looked like it is hardcoded. I corrected it manually, and walla! It just works fine! =)